# Outbound call to a operator to forward to a user

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

The use case is:

1. to make an outbound call to a number where an operator / receptionist picks up
2. Request the operator to transfer the call to the user with the name that we specify.
3. Wait for the user to come on the phone for X seconds
4. And continue the conversation with that user

Now am new to Twilio but have managed to complete 1 and 2.

Edit 1: Details on the flow:
The outbound call is executed with the following piece of code. This calls a number where an operator / receptionist pick up:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create(  
  $to_number,
  $twilio_number,
  array(
    "url" => "http://****/**.php?name=" .$name
  )
);
```

This following is an implementation of 2 and 3. Here we are requesting the operator to transfer this call to the user with the specified `name`.

This works but however I am not sure if this is the best way to do it and hence the question.

```
<Response>
    <Gather ....>
       <Say loop="3"> 
          Please connect us to: <?php print $_REQUEST['name']  ?>.
          Press "1" if we have reached: <?php print $_REQUEST['name'] ?>.
          <Pause/>
        </Say>  
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Here, if the user with the specified `name` pick up then we request him to enter "1"and continue with our processing.

Is there a better way to achieve this use case?

Comment: How have you implemented this so far and what have you tried to complete part 3?

Comment: So are you having difficulty getting the receptionist to forward the call to the user? Where does the name come from in the request? Why do you need the receptionist in the middle of this? How are you making the call in the first place. I'm finding it hard to work all of this out from the TwiML you've shown me so far.

Comment: @philnash updated.

Comment: And how do you want the receptionist to do the forwarding? Can you just look up `$name` in a database and forward the call without including a person?

Comment: no, we would in some situations would have to go through an operator and do not have the extension to automate it.

Comment: Ok, and how do you want the receptionist to do the forwarding? Will they be answering this call on a phone or via a softphone on a computer? What is the user experience you are expecting here?

Comment: a regular phone in almost all the cases.

Comment: The user experience is that the operator transfers the call and so we can begin the next steps in interacting with the specified user.

Comment: So, do you expect the operator to dial the number into their phone and then you forward to that number?

Comment: No, we expect the operator to forward to the user based on the name.

Comment: How will they input the number of the user?

Comment: The operator will transfer the call to the user upon hearing the name. We do not have any insight into how the operator transfers the call.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the system your operator has, so I can't really help here. Since that control of the call is outside of Twilio, I don't know how you'd achieve it and I have nothing to test with either. I hope you find a way to accomplish this.